# Removing jwt token from local storage once shopify public app is uninstalled

Tags: security, jwt, local-storage, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to Shopify platform and have a doubt which I want to clarify.

We are developing a public app on Shopify. Currently we are facing a issue after app uninstall.

Our app contains a login page and we are using jwt based authentication. We are storing jwt token in local storage.

**Now the issue is :**

- When ever our app is uninstalled, we get a uninstall webhook based on which we perform few database operations.
- Now once the app is uninstall, We want to remove jwt token from local storage because after uninstallation of the app, if we try to access our public app specific APIs, they are accessed because JWT token in my local storage exists.

I Somehow want to restrict all kinds of these unethical activities and want to overcome all security flaws.

**As I am new to shopify, Can anyone tell me what better solution for this problem could be ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. How will you possibly control what the user is doing? Make the JWT dependent on some other identifier that changes on every install.

And it's not related to Shopify alone. It's basic principle of JWT.

Comment: No kidding, when you get the webhook for an uninstall, remove any trace of a valid token from your server side system and the problem goes away.